# Error Enabling XBOX Live Creators Program

Tags: xbox-live

It looks like there is an issue enabling an application for XBOX Live Creators program.  The screen times out and throws fatal javascript errors.  I tried in IE 11 and Google Chrome.  Waited 15+ minutes.  It's just bugged.  Here is a screenshot with the Javascript stack trace:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that Creators Program enablement works for a newly created UWP app.  My existing one (18284ShaunTonstad.StellarConquest) must be bugged somehow.  Is there a point of contact I might try reaching out to for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this Shaun - you have indeed found a bug on our side :)

The Xbox Live Creators Program should support any UWP, regardless of when you created it, but we need to fix up something on our back end. We are digging and will let you know as we have a plan.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn-around, it's working with my legacy UWP apps.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with my game. Same error about ProductId. I tried manually setting the variable to my game's ProductId in the JS console and it returns 401 Unauthorized.